# why are unanswered questions not sorted by date?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, unanswered-questions

I am looking to get some rep by answering unanswered questions. I only have time to answer a few at a time. I take a look at the unanswered list and post some good answers (i think) and afterwards I see that the question was posted over a year ago. The odds of that person coming back to that question after such a long time is not good. Besides that, they probably found their answer somewhere else.

So why do these really old questions show up on the first page of the unanswered list? The person that asked that question already thinks the site sucks cause they didn't get help with their question. Why should a newer unanswered question get burried? Do you want people not to find the new question so it yields the same fate?

feature-request: sort unanswered questions by date desc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several tabs near the top of the Unanswered page.  You just need to click the one that says 'newest'.

[image: Newest Unanswered]

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I want to look at Unanswered questions with no answers.  All I see are the most upvoted ones.  This has turned the 'no answers' tab to basically worthless for me.  I don't like the default sort by votes in all situations.  The 'votes' tab is there but the most recent should be the default sort for all of the rest of the tabs.

Comment: Agreed. I want to help unanswered questions without scrolling through the list, but the `no answers` tab is useless as designed.

Comment: My problem was that you can't get unanswered questions (sorted by date) by category. Not by clicking anyway but I just found I can by manipulating the url like: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java

Comment: @developerwjk: Thanks, that works quite smooth