# Add the option to sort unanswered questions by date

Tags: feature-request

Following [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83494/why-are-unanswered-questions-not-sorted-by-date), I would like to be able to sort unanswered questions by date.

The reason is - I don't have much time to answer questions now, and I would like to focus only on the hard ones, that nobody else has answered.

Comment: What's wrong with the method in the the accepted answer on that question, specifically what about http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest doesn't give you want you need?

Comment: just to clarify my earlier comment, there are features *I* think are missing from the sorting and searching for unanswered question, but they may not be what you think are missing.  As this question is written right now, it is a duplicate of the question you referenced, so you need to add some additional clarification so it isn't a duplicate.